# Facebook chat using X-Facebook platform

Tags: c#

I'd like to implement a jabber client to connect to facebook but taking advantage of facebook connect using C#
I tried to do it like the code on facebook which is written in python (http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Integrating_with_Facebook_Chat)
but always gets not-authorized reply .
Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to see the core implementation inside Jaxl library... It's written in PHP, but you should be replicate the exact steps for yourself in C#.... Hope it works for you... http://github.com/abhinavsingh/JAXL